# finding edges of certain color in a graph, python

Tags: python, attributes, networkx

i used the color attribute, coloring two types of edges in my graph.

`G.add_edge(fgh,cde,color='blue')`

(`fgh`, `cde` being variables that are used to connect different elements) (`fgh` and `cde` are part of a loop and their values change with every iteration)

i saved that graph in a gpickle format and now i am trying to get edges of a certain color from the saved graph.

what i want to do is that i get random edges but they have to be of a certain color. thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After loading your graph from the pickle, you could first find all the edges of the color that you are after (see the [documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html#edge-attributes)):

```python
be = []
for e in G.edges_iter():
    if G.edge[e[0]][e[1]]['color'] == 'blue': # or G[e[0]][e[1]]['color']
        be.append(e)
```

or with a list comprehension:

```python
be = [(n1, n2) for n1, n2 in G.edges_iter() if G.edge[n1][n2]['color'] == 'blue']
```

and then choosing random edges with the help of the [`random`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) module, e.g. [`choice`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) or [`sample`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample):

```python
import random

# Select one random edge...
random_blue_edge = random.choice(be)

# ... or several random edges, 3 in this case
random_blue_edges = random.sample(be, 3)
```

However, be sure to check your `be` before calling `random.choice` or `random.sample`. If the sequence is empty when calling `random.choice`, you will get an `IndexError`, and if the sequence is shorter than the number you want to sample in `random.sample`, you will get a `ValueError`.